# Places to Visit in Seattle as a Nirvana Fan?

Tags: sightseeing, history, seattle

I'm planning to visit the Seattle for the first time during summer. I'm a huge fan of Nirvana; and I'm wondering what sorts of places I can visit as a fan?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fortunately one fan [wrote up such a tour idea for the NY Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/03/30/travel/chasing-kurt-cobain-in-washington-state.html).

To summarise, he started by staying at the Marco Polo, a motel where Cobain used to get his heroin nearby, and shoot up in room 226.

413 Fleet Street South is a noted spot next, as the house Cobain lived in with his father for several years in the late 70s / early 80s.

He drives to Aberdeen (town slogan: "Come as you are") (they claim him instead of Seattle), then on to 1210 East First Street (in the Felony Flats - another abode of Cobain's while growing up).

The Aberdeen museum has a statue of Cobain as well.

Aberdeen’s must-see Cobain site is a small park, opened in 2011 by the Kurt Cobain Memorial Foundation, called Kurt Cobain Landing.

There's also several other places where he used to live (address not mentioned), including Dale Crover’s porch, at 609 West Second Street.

He goes to 'The Central' but like many bars of the era, they've changed crowds, styles and music, like 'The Crocodile', the 'OK Hotel', Beehive Records (now a pet store), and Linda's Tavern where Cobain was last seen alive.

As I finish summarising, I realise that the article is actually a bit of a gold mine, because it finishes by listing all the addresses of the places mentioned above, which should help you a lot in planning and locating some of the old haunts.

Good luck!